# PHP GET Request not working

Tags: php, xml, curl, get

When I type `http://rest.example.com/account/get-balance/27e3xxx/7vvU4c95trfxxxx` in browser and hit enter, I get following XML response.

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8" standalone = "yes" ?>
<accountBalance>
    <creditLimit>0.0</creditLimit>
    <quotaEnabled>true</quotaEnabled>
    <value>2.0</value>
</accountBalance>
```

But When I am trying the same URL inside PHP it is sending the response Page not found(**Oops! That page doesn't exist.**). Here are the few ways I try...

Using SimpleXML

```
$content = simplexml_load_file($this->request_uri);
```

Using File methods

```
$content = file_get_contents($this->request_uri);
```

Using CURL

```
    // create a new cURL resource
    $ch = curl_init();

    // set URL and other appropriate options
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $this->request_uri);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

    // grab URL and pass it to the browser
    $content = curl_exec($ch);

    // close cURL resource, and free up system resources
    curl_close($ch);
```

- `$this->request_uri` = same URL I paste in browser. Where I am wrong? Please help me on this. Thank you.

Comment: Agree. Check: 1. cookies 2. referer 3. user-agent

Comment: @Peter, What will happen after checking this? Any hint?

Comment: i meant you should use same Cookies,Referer and User in cURL request as browser does

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is more information that is being transfered from browser to the server than only the URI:

```
http://rest.example.com/account/get-balance/27e3xxx/7vvU4c95trfxxxx
```

By only passing the URI but not passing the other information that gets passed from the browser, you can get different results normally. In your case it is clear that you get different results.

Find out about the other information that get's passed to the server when you request that URI with your browser. This other information is called request-line, request-headers and the body. In a GET request, the request body is normally empty so you only need to concentrate on the request-line and headers, see:

- [**5 Request** - part of Hypertext Transfer Protocol -- HTTP/1.1 RFC 2616 Fielding, et al.](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec5.html)

Contact the technical documentation of your browser if it has so called *network tools*  that are able to display the whole request information for debugging purposes (e.g. Chromium has this, for Firefox there is the Firebug extension that has it).

You can then easily mimic the request with [PHP's HTTP wrapper context options<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/manual/en/context.http.php) or the [Curl extension and it's endless array of options<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) to achieve what you want.

Comment: very nice explanation ... but how my problem will be solved? or what i have to do?

Comment: Any browser same problem, also it shouldn't be browser dependent, this is sms application.

Comment: Any browser same problem? I had read in the question that it works with the browser, now you tell that it does not work in any browsers? Then I highly suggest you contact technical support of the rest service vendor and clarify the issue with them, there must be some technical specification relying on industry standards. Then you can just research the standards that are used, then do some curl learning/training so that you understand how you can use that tool with the standards and then you should be pretty able to figure that out on your own.

Comment: Sorry, it means `using the url inside php` not working with any browsers. When I type the URL direct in browser and hit enter it is working properly.

Comment: thank you so much. problem is solved by adding `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Accept: application/json'));` also `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Accept: application/xml'));`.